# Use JQuery datepicker inside Dynamic Repeater Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I've got a text-box inside a Repeater Control, which is not displayed unless a user-selected checkbox is clicked on.  I can't get the datepicker to function for the date input when the textbox is displayed.

here's some of the repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="BU_Repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_WHS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WHS")%>' Font-Bold="True" OnClick="return showValues(this);"/>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl_IOQ" runat="server" Text="InitialOrderQty" style="display: none;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_IOQ" runat="server" style="display: none;"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:Label ID="lbl_NBD" runat="server" Text="NeedDate" style="display: none;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NBD" runat="server" style="display: none;" class="dummy"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <SeparatorTemplate><hr /></SeparatorTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

There's a javascript function to turn the display-style to 'inline' or 'none' depending on the checkbox.

I've tried both of these (along with other attempts), but still doesnt seem to work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $("[id$=txt_NBD]").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, minDate: 0 }); });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dummy').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I imagine that I'm missing something else ... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does any jQuery work on the page?

Comment: I think the syntax for the id selector should be slightly different: "[id$='txt_NBD']" but I don't see why the class selector doesn't work.

Comment: Holy Crud ... thanks for the question @SBFrancies ... I rechecked and found a typo in the library path ... man, was that costly...